# Insert escaped double quotes into Postgres table using JSON field

Tags: postgresql, psql, jsonb

I am trying to insert a stringified JSON data which looks likes,

```
create table test (exif jsonb);    
insert into test values ('{"name": "maddy", "about": "saying "something" is always good"}');
```

I can able to insert the data using backslash method like below,

```
insert into test values ('{"name": "maddy", "about": "saying \"something\" is always good"}');
```

and the output is also having backslash like below,

```
select * from test
{"name": "maddy", "about": "saying \"something\" is always good"}
```

but, how can I insert the data like this format `{"name": "maddy", "about": "saying "something" is always good"}`. Is it possible, Request you to please give your suggestion.

Comment: The `"` needs to be escaped. It is un-escaped on retrieval: `select '{"name": "maddy", "about": "saying \"something\" is always good"}'::jsonb ->> 'about';  saying "something" is always good`

Comment: select exif->>'name' as name, (exif #>> '{}')::jsonb->>'about' as about from test;

That will work to get the data back without the "\" inside the string but it will give you name and about as two columns though.

Comment: select method is already working fine. Please give suggest inserting method is it possible or not.

Comment: `insert into test values ('{"name": "maddy", "about": "saying \"something\" is always good"}');` works just fine. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1c15f0446220da98fb71393d34f887f8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long observation, cannot insert the data with escaped double quotes. will implement the select method after insertion.

Comment: That's wrong: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1c15f0446220da98fb71393d34f887f8